# How do I verify that the webhook comes from basecamp

Tags: webhooks, basecamp

I have setup webhook to callback into my application server from basecamp 3, but how do I verify that they come from basecamp?
Is there a signature check process?
I can't find a reference in the docs.

Comment: There is no computed signatures for Basecamp webhooks based on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Some webhook allows you to identify the "referrer". For example, I'm using https://webhook.site and it allows me to identify the referrer as https://launchpad.37signals.com/ which is the maker of Basecamp.